# c3p0 initialization fails when using JMockIt

Tags: junit4, c3p0, jmockit

Hit a weird one today.
Some background: basically I'm writing a test case (jUnit 4.10) for a REST service implementation. 
The data layer is using Hibernate3 (love those legacy projects), with c3p0 connection pooling.
All of that is working fine.

BUT, now for the REST service I'm trying to mock a HttpServletRequest (don't ask), using JMockIt.
I have used JMockIt before, and liked it.

RIGHT, so: the problem:
If I run the test case with JUnit on the classpath BEFORE JMockIt (using Netbeans btw), JMockIt complains, and tells me clearly it must be on the classpath BEFORE Junit.

Ok, so I do that.

BUT, then the c3p0 initialization suddenly fails with a NullPointerException (I'll paste the stack trace at the bottom).

If I switch the classpath lib order around again, we are back to where we started.

I don't feel like trying out a different mocking lib now, it's Saturday ffs. And besides, this feels like a really stupid problem....

Anybody come across something like this, or have some thoughts?

Thanks!

The stack trace as promised:

```
    [16-11-2013 11:46:37:037 CAT] ERROR hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider:184 - could not instantiate C3P0 connection pool
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:542)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.pooledDataSource(DataSources.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.configure(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2863)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2859)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1870)
    at za.co.afrigis.doi.hibernate.HibernateSession.init(HibernateSession.java:31)
    at za.co.afrigis.doi.mtn.MtnDoiManager.<init>(MtnDoiManager.java:72)
    at za.co.afrigis.doi.MTNDoiManagerTest.setUpClass(MTNDoiManagerTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.invokeExplosively(JUnit4TestRunnerDecorator.java:44)
    at mockit.integration.junit4.internal.MockFrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(MockFrameworkMethod.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at mockit.internal.util.MethodReflection.invokeWithCheckedThrows(MethodReflection.java:95)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.callMock(MockMethodBridge.java:75)
    at mockit.internal.mockups.MockMethodBridge.invoke(MockMethodBridge.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:520)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1060)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:911)
```

Comment: it looks like, somehow, you are passing to pooledDataSource a Properties object that contains at least one null value. i'm not quite sure how one would arrange that, but it's what would provide precisely this Exception under c3p0 0.9.2.1 and java 7.

Comment: That's the annoying thing - no where am I explicitly building up a Properties object - it's all handled by the org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration object. SO best I can figure is that jMockIt is somehow injecting some naughty somewhere. For now I'll either not use mocking in my tests (which is becoming increasingly challenging), or try a different mocking lib. Thanks for the attempt Steve!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem.  I was using jmockit v1.5 and had a test that talked to some fixture data in a test database. Digging into the jmockit source, I noticed code below in  mockit.internal.startup.Startup.

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.put("jmockit-instrumentation", inst);
```

Apparently, `inst` is null in some instances and this causes the NPE downstream with c3p0 mentioned in the original post.  I didn't figure out why `inst` was null, but when I upgraded to jmockit v1.7 I noticed the library no longer tried to modify system props this way and sure enough my "unit" test (it probably shouldn't be touching the database) is working now.

Shorter answer: try using jmockit v1.7 or newer.

Comment: Thanks sagehen03 - I'll be sure to jump to latest jmockit when/if I get back to that particular project. I'll also set a reminder to come back and mark this as the answer when verified ;)